# Showing $E[x]=\frac{1}{p}$ for a Geometric Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Using the fact that $E(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X \geq k)$, which I previously proved, I have to show that $E[x]=\frac{1}{p}$ for Geometric Random Variable.

I started by saying that $$P(X \leq k)=\sum_{j=1}^k (1-p)^{j-1}p=1-(1-p)^k$.
Since $P(X \leq k)=1-P(X \geq k),$$ then $P(X \geq k)=1-(1-(1-p)^k)=(1-p)^k.$

Then $E(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X \geq k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)^k$, but I don't see how that would equal $1/p$. Did I do something wrong?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You're missing a factor of $x$ in all your expected values.

Comment: @Randall maybe I misunderstood your comment, but that's exactly how the expected value is written in the homework

Comment: Maybe someone else can chime in to confirm, but $E(X) = \sum_x xP(X=x)$ for a discrete RV.

Comment: Edit:  I see that your formulation is an equivalent one to mine.  I've never seen that before.  Carry on....

Comment: @Randall $\mathsf E(X) = \sum_x x \mathsf P(X=x) = \sum_x \mathsf P(X\geq x)$ for a discrete non-negative integer random variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

The sum of a geometric series $\sum^\infty_{k=1}r^k=\frac1{1-r}.$

In your example, $r = 1-p.$
Thus, $\sum^\infty_{k=1}(1-p)^k=\frac1{1-(1-p)}=\frac1p.$

Comment: Well, not quite, $\sum_{k=\color{red}0}^\infty r^k=\frac 1{1-r}$, but Silva was using the wrong function so the errors cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Note: $\mathsf P(X\geq k)= (1-p)^{k-1}$ because $\mathsf P(X\leq k)=1-\mathsf P(X>k)$

$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)^{k-1} \\&= 1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty (1-p)^{k-1} \\&= 1+ (1-p)\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)^{k-1} \\&= 1+(1-p)\mathsf E(X) \\[2ex]\therefore~ \mathsf E(X) &= \frac 1 p\end{align}$